# SP2013: Usage Data Collection Settings

Tags: logging

Under CA -> Monitor -> Configure usage and health data collection. There is a field:

Usage Data Collection Settings
Usage logs must be saved in a location that exists on all servers in the farm. Adjust the maximum size to ensure that sufficient disk space is available.

beside the description above there is Log file location field.

In the SP2010, this area should also contain a field "Maximum size" but it is no longer there on SP2013. May I know why is that and how to change the log behaviour on SP2013?

Answer (score 1):

You can use powershell:

```
Set-SPDiagnosticConfig -LogDiskSpaceUsageGB 500
```

link to Microsoft technet article
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748656(v=office.15).aspx